# Accelerometer vibration detection using a threshold

Tags: c++, arduino, mpu6050, arduino-ultra-sonic

I've program the Accelerometer to detect vibrations by setting a reasonable min/max threshold along all 3-axis' raw data. I need it to only count how many times it detects vibration, however, due to the way it's programmed with the threshold, I used a delay of about 1 sec in order to prevent multiple miscounts, which works but interferes with the Ultrasonic Module (HC-SR04) when it needs to read distance values is synchronously with the Accelerometer. Would like to get some feedback on this.

Comment: Your way of ignoring everythign below a treshold causes a 1 second delay? How? Would you like to show your code in something close to a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you are using Arduino's [`delay()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/delay/) function. Bad idea as you block the all the rest of your application, well, you noticed already...

Better approach just checking if some time elapsed, e. g. using [`millis`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/millis/) function:

```
static bool isDelay = false;
static unsigned long timestamp;

if(detect())
{
    isDelay = true;
    timestamp = millis();
}

if(isDelay && millis() - timestamp > 1000)
{
    isDelay = false;
}
if(!isDelay)
{
    // actions to be taken...
}
```

Always use subtraction between the timestamp and the current time – the time counter might overflow, subtraction result is unaffected, though, and you are safe...

You can simply skip the `isDelay` variable if you are sure enough that the relevant event always occurs at least once in between overflow period (around 50 days):

```
static unsigned long timestamp = millis() - 1000;

if(detect())
{
    timestamp = millis();
}
if(millis() - timestamp > 1000)
{
    // actions to be taken...
}
```

Both variants: static variables as assuming you have this code in Arduino's `loop` function (or one being called from `loop`). Yet prefer replacing the magic number 1000 with a macro and you're fine...